# Implementing accessibility in viewpager android to have a "swipe next for more" kind of thing

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am implementing a viewpager which has multiple hints to a particular functionality. Now when I activate talkback feature it reads the content in the current view. I also want the talkback to say as "swipe left for more hints" how can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer: Don't.  This may be a sensible thing to say if the user is using TalkBack Gestures.  But what if they're using an attached USB keyboard in conjunction with TalkBack?  Is this really the ONLY way to reach those items.  Probably not.  And if it is, you're app may work great for TalkBack gestures, but is broken for switch access and keyboard access.  TalkBack users know how to use TalkBack, switch users know how to use switches, etc.  Use good, common design patterns in your layouts, and let users figure things out for themselves.

Let's explain this in a different way.  Let's say you have a button.  You have marked this thing up so it looks like a button.  Do you have a big sign next to your button that says "HEY, CLICK YOUR MOUSE HERE TO ACTIVATE THIS BUTTON"... no of course not.  Users know how to use buttons.  Use reasonable design idioms, and users should understand how your UI works, independent of whether they are using TalkBack, Switches, Keyboards, etc.  It is misleading, inappropriate, and actually LESS accessible to include TalkBack gesture specific instructions on how to perform actions.

See WCag 2.0 Guideline 4.1

Comment: But if its a requirement.. Is there a way to do it??

Comment: If it's a requirement, it shouldn't be.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it.  Private message me if this post hasn't convinced the person who came up with this requirement to change it, and we can discuss further.

Comment: I am not able to private chat... As using a mobile app..dont know how to do it ?

Comment: It's not that you can't.  It's that it's a bad idea.  What if the user can't swipe and is using switch access instead?  This direction then becomes unhelpful and innacurate.